# How to add `if` inside for or foreach?

Tags: php

I'm trying to add php `if` inside 4 foreach if not set or found.Here is an example

```
$images = "image1,image2,image3";
$covers = "cover1,cover2,cover3";
$titles = "title1,title2";
$albums = "album1,album2";

$images = explode(',', $images);
$covers = explode(',', $covers);
$titles = explode(',', $titles);
$albums = explode(',', $albums);

for ($index = 0; $index < count($images); $index++)
{
  echo "$images[$index] - $covers[$index] - $titles[$index] - $albums[$index]</br>";  
}
```

Output is :

```
    image1 - cover1 - title1 - album1
    image2 - cover2 - title2 - album2
    Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 19
    Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in C:\wamp\www\index.php on line 19image3 - cover3 - -
```

Need output:

```
   image1 - cover1 - title1 - album1
   image2 - cover2 - title2 - album2
   image3 - cover3 -  - 
   image4 - cover4 -  -
```

Comment: `if(!$titles[$index]){$titles[$index] = '';}
if(!$albums[$index]){$albums[$index] = '';}`
or simply turn off notice reports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to look at [`isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php)

You can add something like this

```
for ($index = 0; $index < count($images); $index++) {

    echo "$images[$index] - $covers[$index]";

    if ( isset($titles[$index]) ) {
        echo " - $titles[$index]";
    } else {
        echo " -";
    }
    if ( isset($albums[$index]) ) {
        echo " - $albums[$index]";  
    } else {
        echo " -";
    }

    echo "</br>";
}
```

Comment: What shows you undefined? Willing to help just need the info to be a bit more specific